# PipeLine Processing Engine

Tags: c#, pipeline, chain-of-responsibility

```
P1---->P2----->(output 1)
P1---->P3---->(output 2)
(output 1) + (output 2) ---->P4
```

P1 Process execute, P1 output is entered in P2 process as a input. P2 will also execute. P4 should start only when P2 & P3 complete process. P4 Process will not started since input process P3 is not yet processed (P2 input is available now).

Any input parameter trigger mechanism which will trigger P4 execute process.
I need any standard design pattern or sample code (C#) which will solve above problem.

Also need any standard way by which we can execute process parallel in .net 3.5 framework.

Answer (score 1):

I have been thinking about this some day earlier.
First, create a interface:

```
public interface IXXX{
    void Process(Model model);
}
public class P1:IXXX{...} //same for p2 p3 p4...
```

Model contains the input parameters and the output result.
p1 p2 are all implement this interface.
Each of the processors changes some parts of the result (Model property).
Use an IOC container and register p1 and p2 with the container as interfaces (or you can write some simple code do this).
Get all instances of the interface:

```
var processors=ServerLocator.GetServices<IXXX>
```

It will return an `IEnumerable<IXXX>`. This list contains all the instances of the classes that implement interface IXXX ([p1,p2,p3...]).

```
var model=new Model();//empty model with input param
foreach(var processor in processors)
{
    processor.Prosess(model);
}
```

If you want to control the process order, you can add a method to the interface:

```
int Order();
```

and each class (p1,p2) returns a different value (1,2).
Then order by this value.
You stop when done with a process
(for example, there are p1 p2 p3 p4, when p3 done, there is some condition, don't do p4).
You can add a bool property in model, like `DoNext`. It should be false by default, and in p3, change it to true. So you can pass the left
and in foreach{}, you can create a task for each of prossecor, run all the processors in different threads (but I think that is not a pipeline).
I am not good at English. I hope this can help you.

**Update：**

```
public interface IProcessor
{
    void Process(Model model);
    int Order();
}
public class P1 : IProcessor
{
    public void Process(Model model)
    {
    }

    public int Order()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class P2 : IProcessor
{
    public void Process(Model model)
    {
    }

    public int Order()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}

public class P3 : IProcessor
{
    public void Process(Model model)
    {
    }

    public int Order()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}

public class P4 : IProcessor
{
    public void Process(Model model)
    {
    }

    public int Order()
    {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

first step,run only p1, second step,async run p2 and p3,third step run p4.

```
var processors = DependencyResolver.Current.GetServices<IProcessor>();
var group = processors.GroupBy(x => x.Order()).OrderBy(x => x.Key);
var model = new Model();
foreach (var item in group)
{
    var tasks = item.Select(x => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => x.Process(model))).ToArray();
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}
```

I think this is what you want
DependencyResolver is in asp.net mvc,you can change it to any other ioc container or use common service locator

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply.
Yes, true, it’s not exactly pipeline. You can say concurrent pipeline. 
Every process Output will be used as a Input for next process. Every process will start processing once all required input processes (output of previous process) received.

P4 should not be started until P2 & P3 process completed.
P2 & P3  output will be used as input for processor P4.

Once P2 & P3 output ready, it should trigger to start P4 process.

Waiting for your reply. What about “Chain of Responsibility” pattern?

Comment: you can use Order(),same order run async,diffrent order run sync.you can groupby order(),order by key(order number) ,then foreach,in foreach use task run async,and wait them complete

Comment: Hi  ChenZ, 
Once again thanks for the quick reply. One question, I have .Net 3.5 version support. “Task” supports comes from .Net 4.0 version onward, is there any other way around to do this in .Net 3.5 version like Thread Pool etc. Waiting for your reply. :)

Comment: loop check each thread's ThreadState to find if the thread done.

Comment: Thanks Chenz, i am trying parallel task run through ThreadPool or Background worker thread in .Net 3.5.  Will let you know if require your help. Thanks for your efforts & prompt help.